# ¿Como puedo encriptar la cadena de conexión de mi web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web.config

¿Se puede encriptar de alguna forma la cadena de conexión (`connectionStrings`) de mi archivo `Web.config`? ¿Como seria?.

Los datos a encriptar serian los básicos:

Username, Password...

Comment: aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "ruta del webconfig"

Comment: no se si darle voto positivo o negativo al comentario de arriba.... esa es la respuesta "correcta", pero no tiene nada de contexto

Comment: Por lo que puse investigar el comentario de arriba solo es para el iis..